# Stop/start WCF MEX service at runtime

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, wcf

Is it possible/how do I stop and start the HTTP MEX listener of a self hosted WCF service at runtime without affecting the primary WCF service?

(Please don't ask why I want to do this.  It is a hack to get around artificial limitations imposed by someone else.)

Comment: Where would you do that?  In your self-host code?  Under what circumstances?

Comment: It would be in the self-hosted service.  Whenever internal parameters are met.

Comment: A simple but complete answer with code has been posted.

Comment: Re-added my answer with fixed up code and better explanation about its assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*****[Re-added this answer after re-test and code cleanup]  This is actual code that I  have added to my generic WCF-based service development framework and it is fully tested.*****

Assuming that you start with MEX enabled on the `ServiceHost`...

> The following solution is written in
>   terms of a `ServiceHost` subclass
>   (`WCFServiceHost<T>`) that implements
>   a special interface (`IWCFState`) for
>   storing an instance of the MEX
>   `EndpointDispatcher` class.

First, add these namespaces...

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
```

Secondly, define the `IWCFState` interface...

```
public interface IWCFState
{
    EndpointDispatcher MexEndpointDispatcher
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Thirdly, create a static class for some `ServiceHost` extension methods (we'll fill them in below)...

```
public static class WCFExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveMexEndpointDispatcher(this ServiceHost host){}

    public static void AddMexEndpointDispatcher(this ServiceHost host){}
}
```

Now let's fill in the extension methods...

### Stopping MEX on a `ServiceHost` at Runtime

```
public static void RemoveMexEndpointDispatcher(this ServiceHost host)
{
    // In the simple example, we only define one MEX endpoint for
    // one transport protocol
    var queryMexChannelDisps = 
            host.ChannelDispatchers.Where(
                disp => (((ChannelDispatcher)disp).Endpoints[0].ContractName
                                            == "IMetadataExchange"));
    var channelDisp = (ChannelDispatcher)queryMexChannelDisps.First();

    // Save the MEX EndpointDispatcher
    ((IWCFState)host).MexEndpointDispatcher = channelDisp.Endpoints[0];

    channelDisp.Endpoints.Remove(channelDisp.Endpoints[0]);
}
```

Then call it like this...

```
// WCFServiceHost<T> inherits from ServiceHost and T is the Service Type,
// with the new() condition for the generic type T.  It encapsulates 
// the creation of the Service Type that is passed into the base class 
// constructor.
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("someValidURI");
WCFServiceHost<T> serviceImplementation = new WCFServiceHost<T>(baseAddress);

// We must open the ServiceHost first...
serviceImplementation.Open();

// Let's turn MEX off by default.
serviceImplementation.RemoveMexEndpointDispatcher();
```

### Starting MEX (again) on a `ServiceHost` at Runtime

```
public static void AddMexEndpointDispatcher(this ServiceHost host)
{
    var queryMexChannelDisps =
            host.ChannelDispatchers.Where(
                    disp => (((ChannelDispatcher)disp).Endpoints.Count == 0));
    var channelDisp = (ChannelDispatcher)queryMexChannelDisps.First();

    // Add the MEX EndpointDispatcher
    channelDisp.Endpoints.Add(((IWCFState)host).MexEndpointDispatcher);
}
```

Then call it like this...

```
serviceImplementation.AddMexEndpointDispatcher();
```

### Summary

This design allows you to use some messaging methods to send a command to the service itself or to code that is hosting the service and have it carry out the enabling or disabling of a MEX `EndpointDispatcher`, effectively turning off MEX for that `ServiceHost`.

Note: This design assumes that the code will support MEX at startup, but then it will use a config setting to determine if the service will disable MEX after calling `Open()` on the `ServiceHost`.  This code will throw if you attempt to call either extension method before the `ServiceHost` has been opened.

Considerations: I would probably create a special service instance with management operations that did not support MEX at startup and establish that as service control channel.

### Resources

I found the following two resources indispensable while figuring this out:

- .NET Reflector: *class browser, analyzer & decompiler for inspecting assemblies like System.ServiceModel.dll*: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/
- Extending Dispatchers (MSDN): provides a fantastic high-level diagram of the class composition of a WCF service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665.aspx

Comment: I am not completely satisfied with my solution: 1) I don't like assuming only 1 EndpointDispatcher and specifying ContractName instead of comparing a type; 2) I don't like assuming that the MEX ChannelDispatcher has 0 endpoints and that it is the only such ChannelDispatcher.

Comment: I also do not like the extension methods themselves, because of the need to embed the cast to IWCFSTate.  Therefore, I might just move them into my WCFServiceHostUtils static class instead.

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely helpful.  I modified my version a bit to support multiple Mex endpoints, and it works as desired.

Comment: I am glad!  If you have any links to resources that might have helped you any further, like on a way to support multiple Mex endpoints, I would love to see that.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my '2 Mex endpoints' are nothing more than an artifact of my learning WCF.  There is actually only 1 Mex address exposed.